# Is there a limit with the number of SSL connections?

Tags: ssl

Is there a limit with the number of SSL connections?

We are trying to connect through SSL with 2000 sessions. We have tried it a couple of times but it always dies at 1062nd. Is there a limit?

Comment: Connect to what? Using what? I think you'll need to provide more details to get help.

Answer (score 3):

Your operating system will have a limit on the number of open files if you are on linux
ulimit -a will show your various limits.

I imagine yours is set to 1024 and some of the sessions just happened to have closed allow the figure of 1062 (this last bit is a guess)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything has a limit. As far as I'm aware, there is no inherit limit with "SSL".. it is after all just a protocol.

But, there is a limited amount of memory, ports, CPU on the machine you are connected to, from and every single one in between.

The actually server you are connected to may have an arbitrary limit set too.

This question doesn't have enough information to answer beyond "YES".

Answer (score 1):

SSL itself doesn't have any limitations, but there are some practical limits you may be running into:

- SSL connections require more resources on both ends of the connection, so you may be hitting some built-in server limit.
- TCP/IP uses a 16-bit port number to identify connections, only some of which (around 16,000) are used for dynamic client connections.  This would limit the number of active connections a single client could make to the same server.
- On Linux, each process has a maximum number of file descriptors that it can have open, and each network connection uses one file descriptor.  I imagine Windows has a similar limit.