# Can servers limit the number of incoming TLS connections?

Tags: tcp, rate-limiting

I wrote a Java application that communicates with a [3rd-party server](https://api.kucoin.com/) that is hosted on AWS. According to what I've read, there are no connection limits on their REST API, yet regardless of how many threads I try to hit them with I am seeing a limit of 64 outgoing connections.

My client is written in Java, running under Windows 10. This number smells like an intentional limit, but I have been unable to find any documented limits specific to the aforementioned environment.

I tried pointing my application to `https://test.com/` and got a limit of 128 outgoing connections which leads me to believe the limit is server-side.

**How can one determine (from the client's side) whether outgoing connections are being restricted by the server-side?** (I tried `netstat -an` but I only saw `ESTABLISHED` connections)

Seeing as my application is not receiving any connection failures from the server, could they be intentionally withholding [SYN-ACK responses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) until older connections are closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's no reliable way to tell from a client's side what the outgoing connections are being restricted to (and that would seem like a security issue to me if you could).

As for what the limits are, I think that also could be a difficult thing to determine from the server itself (unless it was configured at some lower bound) as there would probably be a lot of variables such as pretty much everything, from the [amount of memory, ports, CPU on the machine you are connected to, from and every single one in between.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686/is-there-a-limit-with-the-number-of-ssl-connections)

Also 64 and 128 don't seem like human set limits to me, but instead limits on something internal as it's a power of 2.

Comment: Many humans involved in computing like powers of 2 as "nice round numbers".